# Automated Hover Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

So, I built this web page at http://ecofixoil.co.nz with help from a template. The yellow buttons across the top are an adaptation of a few css scripts I found to get them to do what they do when you hover over and click them. Now I want an automated hover effect to get them to automatically act like you are hovering over them each for a second when the page loads, then reacts to the mouse as an override. I have searched the web but haven't found any solution I can work.

Can I install an over-riding script to simulate mouse-hover over them?

Comment: You can't trigger :hover with JS. I'd suggest to use the same styling for :hover and for some className you can add with JS. Visually it'll be what you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the CSS in the `<head></head>` section:

```
<style type="text/css">
.tooltip.hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0.95;
}

.tooltip.hover a {
    top: -5px;
}
</style>
```

Add the javascript before your `</body>` closing tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        timer = 1000;

        $('.efo_icons .tooltip').each(function() {
            var icon = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                icon.addClass('hover');
            }, timer);
            timer += 1000;

            setTimeout(function() {
                icon.removeClass('hover');
            }, timer);

        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: That works awesomely. Thanks very much.

Comment: Just one thing, is it possible to have it going in an endless loop but stops and is overridden by actual mouse hover over the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a css class to your elements

```
$(".button").addClass("hoverEffect");
```

then you can simply use the same styling for that class as on hover

```
.button:hover, .button.hoverEffect {
    /* your css */
}
```

To remove the effect simply remove the css class.

```
$(".button").removeClass("hoverEffect");
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS it's not impossible, but it would require quite a lot of code. A Javascript alternative might me more maintenance friendly.

```css
.tooltip {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  width: 250px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

a {
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a:after {
  content: url("http://placehold.it/50");
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.icon:nth-child(1) .tooltiptext {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: darkslategray;
  color: white;
  animation: tool 1s linear;
}

.icon:nth-child(1) {
  animation: anim 1s linear;
}

.icon:nth-child(2) .tooltiptext {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: darkslategray;
  color: white;
  animation: tool 1s 1s linear;
}

.icon:nth-child(2) {
  animation: anim 1s 1s linear;
}

.icon:nth-child(3) .tooltiptext {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: darkslategray;
  color: white;
  animation: tool 1s 2s linear;
}

.icon:nth-child(3) {
  animation: anim 1s 2s linear;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    top: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: -1em;
  }
}

@keyframes tool {
  from {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    top: -4em;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <a href="#industrial" class="icon efo_cog">
    <span class="tooltiptext">Industrial<br>and Mechanical</span>
  </a>

  <a href="#industrial" class="icon efo_cog">
    <span class="tooltiptext">Industrial<br>and Mechanical</span>
  </a>
  
  <a href="#industrial" class="icon efo_cog">
    <span class="tooltiptext">Industrial<br>and Mechanical</span>
  </a>
</div>
```